# Using "Allow From" in the .htaccess file - what IP to enter?

Tags: .htaccess

this is my htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName “Sorry, Restricted Area!”
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Allow from 123.45.67.890
Satisfy Any
```

My question is about the Allow from line ... the IP I give here is the callers IP, isnt it? This htaccess file is on my server which has 123.45.67.890 as IP, but as soon as I activate this htaccess, I can call the website it protects from anywhere, not just from the server itself, which is the plan. I call it like this: http://123.45.67.890/website ... question is, why can I call it from any computer even though it has the IP restriction? The site should onlybe called from the server itself.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to deny from all first:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 888.888.888.888
```

Comment: Not working, this blocks all access, even from the server which has the IP I entered in the htaccess.

Comment: Kind of odd, when I google it now, I get very similar results: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/htaccess-deny-from-all-restrict-directory-access.html